# How to override default behaviour of ReadMoreTextView pod to not prevent links from detecting?

Tags: ios, swift

I simply use [ReadMoreTextView](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView) library with cocoapods in my project.

And this is how it is implemented:

```
let textView: UITextView = {
    let view = ReadMoreTextView(maximumNumberOfLines: 5)
    view.textColor = .mineShaft
    view.isScrollEnabled = false
    view.isEditable = false
    view.dataDetectorTypes = [.link]
    view.textAlignment = .left
    view.textContainerInset = .zero
    view.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    return view
}()
```

with simple extension:

```
extension ReadMoreTextView {
    convenience init(maximumNumberOfLines: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.maximumNumberOfLines = maximumNumberOfLines
        shouldTrim = true
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work and do not detect links. Why? When I replace `ReadMoreTextView` with `UITextView` then everything is all right and works. Can I somehow override the default behavior of this?

Answer (score -1):

i'm sorry ,i have also studied the `ReadMoreTextView` library for a long time ,then i can detect the link but there is no click event response.

##### my code as follow:

```
 let textView: ReadMoreTextView = {
        let view = ReadMoreTextView(maximumNumberOfLines:100);
        view.textColor = UIColor.red;
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray;
        view.dataDetectorTypes = [.link]
        view.isScrollEnabled = false
        view.isEditable = true
        view.textAlignment = .left
        view.textContainerInset = .zero
        view.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        return view
    }()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       textView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 400);
       textView.text  = "Lorem http://ipsum.com dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda,detect link will link string."
       view.addSubview(textView)
       textView.delegate = self;
       let attStr : NSMutableAttributedString = textView.attributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
        print(attStr);
//        let attStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
       let content : String = textView.text
       let linkStr : String = "will link string"
//        let linkStrOther : String = "will link  other string"
       let toogleProtocol :String = "userProtocol://"
        
       if (content as NSString).range(of: linkStr).location != NSNotFound {
            attStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: toogleProtocol, range: (content as NSString).range(of: linkStr))
        }
       print(attStr);
       textView.attributedText = attStr
       ///Only one color can be set
       textView.linkTextAttributes =  [
           NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue
       ]
  }
  enum ClickLinkType {
        case userProtocol
        case privacyPolicy
    }
  var clickHandle:((_ clickType:ClickLinkType)->())?
    
  func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
           if URL.scheme  ==  "userProtocol"{
               self.clickHandle?(.userProtocol)
               return false
           }else if URL.scheme == "privacyPolicy"{
               self.clickHandle?(.privacyPolicy)
               return false
           }
           return true
     }
```

you can take a look at `ExpandableLabel` library, it should solve your problem.

Comment: comment out ```view.isEditable = false ``` this line, I test can detect the link

Comment: then the return value is modified to ```ReadMoreTextView``` 
instead of ```UITextView```

Comment: Does ExpandableLabel works with links and open them when tapped?